# The Most Powerful Number

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers

A power-full number is defined as a number with $n$ amount of non-zero digits $D_x$.
The number takes the form $D_n$&$...$&$D_2$&$D_1$. The digits in a power-full number satisfies the rule
  $D_{x+1}$&$D_x=k_x^{x+1}$ where $k_x$ are positive integers. This rule applies for $1\le x\lt n$.

Essentially a power-full number has paired digits that equal some perfect power corresponding to its position in the chain + 1.

Given that the magnitude of a power-full number and $n$ determines how *powerful* it is (the bigger the better), what is the **most *powerful* number?**

Comment: Feel free to help with formatting if there is an easier way to convey this puzzle

Comment: Do you mean kx are positive integers or is there a single k?

Comment: Oops, fixed! @JonathanAllan

Comment: My edits were to make the spelling consistent; now you have both 'power-full' and 'powerful' in your title and body. Pedants may think the definitions are different ...

Comment: @Veedrac $1\le x\lt n$ shouldn't include $n$. I thought it would be more confusing to have $1\le x\le n-1$

Comment: @Adam nvm, I was being dumb.

Comment: @Veedrac Haha no problem ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the most powerful number is

> 1649, $n=4$ (or, if zeros are allowed: 01649, $n=5$)

It's powerful since

> 49 is a square, 64 a third power, 16 a fourth power (and 01 a fifth power).

In order to have a more powerful number

> with $n=6$, it needs to start with two digits forming a sixth power, so either 01 or 64. However, there is no two-digit fifth power starting with 1 or 4; we have only 01 and 32.
>  Another $n=5$ powerful number without zeros should start with 32, but there's no two-digit fourth power starting with 2, so that's impossible too.
>  Another $n=4$ powerful number could start with 81, but there are no two-digit third powers starting with one. Similarly, there are no other two-digit third powers starting with 6 than 64, so no improvement can be made there either.

Comment: To complete the demonstration, you should add why you can't have the same n but the leading digit being the number of letters of the 5th word of your answer. (the reason is similar to what you already said)

Comment: @Evargalo you're right, thanks; updated